# Typescript. Is it possible to pass a dynamic type into a function (ts error: 2322)

Tags: typescript, function, types, dynamic

Is it possible to pass a dynamic type in TypeScript to a function

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIEEAOwBKEDOmA9iPhADwAqAfMgN4CwAUMsgCZxhwD8AXMpWQAfZCACuAGwnNW0KESh96M1snxcwY-P3EBbAEbQVrEHF0R+6qKADmx5Ofz44Ni2rDWQdlsgC+zfyZmMABPTBRUAFUyKAARTjhkAF40LFwCYlIKRh8YYCh1U3NLD1sA6mZgsIicIgkIeK5k1Ow8QhIychzWCThCszcrMqZfCqCmPpCQBGQYMWmwYBJkDzhSGAVdPABHMQIwKmoACg4ufkoASn4ABXldYE6aZR8AehfkWKJbNSJzFf38Co3gIABYoU6JB6iIhgZAIBRQCAIMAAGjQ7CRwDYKDARGQD3we2Qa2QcgUKkRmigIGeqlJUHkUH43Tp7k4Wn4ABYAAyclH2EwDfgAcgAcjCAGJEeZsYX8nx0xzOVwi8WwqUyuX2QKsXwAbgClSYwN0cAA1hAdnt1HCSbtoCFobCSBJHVpoPhkPoxLC4BJ8HjyPJ6vg0cQbQpkDCwVB2AkxpNprN5siljTTRarftDkcxFAJCVPDYrshbr8HhQniz4aRYYj2llmnAAO5wYCwmAQMAIEG5-MXA0+Gs2iFN1vt5D1zJkAB0ACsAyAjgOKV28zTVutNln1DmISuRkajomZsvkrRqx1Ye7YykW23YRnLRB7buojFGnBjsKQWAwJhtDeCQiAQP0QSIdQXjgbAXhvF4AEZhQPXwDyAA)

```
interface IApiResponse<T> {
  data?: T | null
  error?: {
    status: number
    name: string
    message: string
  }
}

type IUserData = IApiResponse<{
  firstname: string
}>

type IRoleData = IApiResponse<{
  lastname: string
}>
```

Doing some tests. The data is not correct, I decide to issue an error.

```
async function transformRequest<T>(data: T): Promise<T> {
  return {
    error: {
      status: 404,
      name: 'NotFound',
      message: 'Not Found',
    }
  };
}
```

makeRequest can query not only users but also <roles, post or other data>

```
async function makeRequest<T>(url: string): Promise<T> {
  const response = await fetch(url);
  const data = await response.json();
  return transformRequest<T>(data);
}

(async () => {
  const user = await makeRequest<IUserData>('https://localhost/api/user/1');
});
```

Comment: You mean return a dynamic type from a function?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Your code as written doesn't work because the implementation of `makeUser()` cannot know which subtype of `IUserDefaultDto` the caller wants, so `{id: 1, name: 'Name'}` may not be acceptable. I don't understand why you are using generics; the code, as written, should not use them: see [this version](//tsplay.dev/w2p39m) instead. If that fully addresses your question, I could write an answer. Otherwise, please [edit] to show what I'm missing; specifically, what are you attempting to do with the generic type argument? (Please mention @jcalz to notify me if you reply)

Comment: Maybe this example would be more illustrative shorturl.at/qvNOU

Comment: Since you did not mention @jcalz in your comment, I was not alerted, so it is merely coincidence that I have seen this again.  The example is still confusing.  How does the *compiler* know that `makeRequest()` should return a `Promise<IUserData>`? If the user can call `makeRequest<IUserData>("")` they can also call `makeRequest<string>("")`?  So what you are doing is inherently unsafe.  Can you explain what the point is? Maybe you just want a type assertion to suppress the error, but it's not any safer.

Comment: I wanted to make some functions to work with API requests. I tried all day and came up with this solution
[Playground](https://shorturl.at/rOTW1)

Comment: [Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mL5yVW)